# Как аккуратно написать условие? шаблонизатор smarty

Tags: php, smarty, шаблонизаторы

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста, со шаблонизатором smarty. Как сделать проверку, если {%$image.value%} в начале названия содержит "https" то вывести в таком формате

```
<li class="gallery-img-wrapper" data-thumb="{%$image.value%}" data-src="{%$image.value%}">
```

если нет то так

```
 <li class="gallery-img-wrapper" data-thumb="{%$settings.patch%}uploads/images/ts/{%$image.value%}" data-src="{%$settings.patch%}uploads/images/tb/{%$image.value%}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{if strlen($image.value) > 4}
{if substr($image.value, 0, 5) == 'https'}
    ТУТ ВЫВОД ДЛЯ HTTPS
{else}
    ТУТ ВЫВОД ДЛЯ HTTP
{/if}
{else}
    // image.value имеет малую длину
{/if}
```

Яб много всякого еще пихнул бы из проверок, но думаю смысл ясен, а там дальше сами разберетесь.

**P.S.1.** В идеале вот такой вариант будет корректным, попробуйте с ним если заработает:

```
{if strtolower(substr($image.value, 0, 5)) == 'https'}
```

**P.S.2.** Если не уверены какие там будут кодировки, то : `mb_strlen`, `mb_strtolower` и `mb_substr`.

P.S.3. Если уверены что строка всегда содержит URL, то первое условие можно удалить.

Comment: `{if $image.value|strlen > 4}` или `{$imag.value|substr:0:5}` это больше в стиле шаблонов smarty.